# Group JSON values to display in React Dropdown list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm getting my JSON data as such:

```
{ 
   "cars": [
       {
          "make":"BMW",
          "model":"X3",
          "Lot":"Used"
       },
       {
          "make":"BMW",
          "model":"520",
          "Lot":"Used"
       },
       {
          "make":"Mercedes",
          "model":"550",
          "Lot":"New"
        },
        {
           "make":"Mercedes",
           "model":"C400",
            "Lot":"Used"
         }
     ]
}
```

I want to group them by the make to show in my dropdown list like so:

```
 BMW
     Used
        X3
       520
 Mercedes
      New
         550
      Used
         C400
```

I'm currently using this on a React page and I have the dropdown populated, I'd like to group them as such instead of showing everything on one line for each record

Comment: Please post at least an attempt at reducing the data into the shape that you need. This isn't a place to just get solutions without an attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You could `Array#reduce` over it group by `make`, `model` and `Lot` keys.

```js
const group = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, { make, Lot, model }) => {
  if (!acc[make]) {
     acc[make] = {};
  }
  
  (acc[make][Lot] || (acc[make][Lot] = [])).push(model);

  return acc;
}, {});

const json={"cars":[{"make":"BMW","model":"X3","Lot":"Used"},{"make":"BMW","model":"520","Lot":"Used"},{"make":"Mercedes","model":"550","Lot":"New"},{"make":"Mercedes","model":"C400","Lot":"Used"}]}

console.log(group(json.cars));
```

Answer (score 0):

@topched
Right now, I'm just binding the data from my API. like so:

```
const getAllCars = () => {
  allCars.GetAllCars()
    .then((response) => {
       setallCars(response.data)
   })
     .catch((e) => { console.log(e)}

}

return (
  <select> 
   <option value ='0'>
     { carTypes.map(data => (
        <option
           value={data.make}
         >
         { data.make }
        </option>
      )
 )
```

As I mentioned, I'm just binding the data, without the grouping.